# Enumerative characterisation of boolean lattices II

Tags: co.combinatorics, lattice-theory, posets, enumerative-combinatorics

This is a sequel of this [post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/248566/34538).

The boolean lattice $B_n$ is [graded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_poset) with rank numbers $\binom{n}{0}, \binom{n}{1}, \dots, \binom{n}{n}$, and $n2^{n-1}$ edges.

*Question*: Is a graded lattice with the above rank numbers and $n2^{n-1}$ edges, equivalent to $B_n$?

If it is not true, it would be useful (to me) to know up to which $n$ it is true.

Answer (score 3):

True for $n \le 4$. For $n \le 3$ it is straightforward.

For $n=4$, inspect all 16-element vertically indecomposable graded lattices ([listed here](https://b2share.eudat.eu/records/dbb096da4e364b5e9e37b982431f41de)). The list has 1900132 lattices; of them, 103411 have rank sequence 1,4,6,4,1, and 249 have exactly 32 edges. But only 1 lattice has both, that's the $B_4$.